# Magento Shopping cart price rule / coupon on product variations within a category

Tags: magento, coupon

We're trying to setup a coupon (10%) for all products in a certain category (id:20) in magento.

The rule only seems to work when we assign the simple variations of a product to a category but we never do this, we only assign the configurables. Am I missing something obvious or is this just the way it is? I don't want to add every single variation to the category as they are all set to be Not Visible Individually and it seems overkill.

We're on Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

just go  to admin->Promotion->Catalog price Rules-> Add new Rule -> Fill all the rule information -> fill the condition by seleting the category name -> Fill the Action .

Thats It Save the rules.

Comment: I know how to create the rule. It's all be done. It only works when the simple variations are added directly to the category. So if I have a Jacket which is in category ID 20, the rule will only work if I add the SMALL RED JACKET to category ID 20 too.

Comment: i think you want each product of same category would have different rules . Is it ?

Please specify us.